# BigQuery view appears to be generating huge number of Queries

Tags: google-bigquery, view

I have a View which is populated by a SQL request to a regular dataset. As far as I know, not a soul is looking at that view (at least not very often). But if I go to the View and click on Project History then there is an IAM service account which is running the query every 15 seconds. Each query is shuffling 2.55 MB and reading 70,000 records, so I'd really prefer that it didn't do this.

The dataset source to create the view shows that it's last modified date was 3 days ago, so the service account is not being trigged by a change in the source. I checked the job scheduler and nothin there. So what is triggering it and how can I tell it to calm down?

Comment: For Looker Studio this query is rate to high;  I guess for a tool such as Dataprep. Can you contact the IAM responsable? Otherwise, please open the view and press the "copy" button. If the copy of the view is also query by the IAM service account, this account should be closed immediately! Otherwise, delete the view and see who complains and tell maybe your collogues that there is a new name for this view.

Comment: The IAM service account doing the DDOC on me is indeed a service account. I cant find a parameter that tells the service account how often to ping. However, I was just reading about maintenance views, and that they populate by default every 30 minutes, which sounds just fine. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: I think I found the issue. There is a SEEQ connector attached to BQ and every six seconds it is asking for the latest time stamp from the view. But the view itself is a complicated query from a big dataset, so to get the latest time it runs the big query (no pun intended). I changed to a materialized view. The SEEQ pings still arrive, but they are harmless because the materialized view can answer very quickly. Then once every 30 minutes the materialized view refreshes and that chats to the big database, Appreciate the help, regards,